# Stuck at Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Today I got a new project to work on:

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.16
- And file `.rvmrc` with content `rvm use 1.9.3@somegemset --create`

I started `bundle install` and nothing happen, it's just stuck at `Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/` forever. I went through issues on bundler repo, follow many answers on Stackoverflow, but nothing help.

Why it is stuck here?

> Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/

Answer (score 1):

After hours of researching and playing around, I was able to get it work by not using `.rvmrc`. I removed the file and just keep using the same ruby version without gemset, et voila the `bundle install` running perfectly.

I still don't understand what is the main issue of this, really appreciate if anyone can explain it.

Comment: It could be that gemset was corrupted and Bundler got lost trying to resolve dependencies.